# Values of Boolean array

Tags: c#

Is there any way how to check if boolean array contains only true (or false) values or i need to check it value by value like this

```
for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
{
   if (CheckPart[k] == false) Checked = false;
}
```

I know this is simple and works, but only for curiosity.

Comment: You can do this by many ways, but all are same. Your way is right. You can break loop after finding `false` element.

Comment: Even if there was a one-line method on the array, it would still take linear time for its implementatiom to find the result...

Comment: @H2CO3: but there are improvements that can be made. eg the above code will always complete the for loop. You could however break out of it after finding a single false which at least one of the current answers does.

Comment: Please clarify if you want to check if the array contains only the same value (all true, or all false), or true for all true and false otherwise.

Comment: @Chris Nevertheless, that still takes linear time. (Yes, I do use `break;` in search loops, of course.)

Comment: @H2CO3: Agreed. My point was that just because all solutions are linear doesn't mean that all solutions are equal. For a 10 element array probably irrelevant but the short circuiting could have a massive performance impact if you are looking at millions of items in the array. If my maths is right (which it may not be because I did it in my head) a shortcircuit approach will be five times faster on average for a ten element array. And this comment is less for your benefit (since you sound like you know this already) but for anybody else who comes along and reads the comments here.

Comment: @chris Fair enough, asymptotic complexity is called asymptotic and not 'identical' for a reason ;-)

Comment: @Chris The speed increase is entirely dependent on the values of the array.  If they're random that's one thing, but it's highly unlikely they're truly random.

Comment: @Servy: Ironically it seems that comment and mine on one of the answers below to you said the same thing nearly. ;-) Yes, you're right but if they tend towards being false then it will be even better than five times and if they tend to true then it will be worse than five times. I still think 5x is a reasonable estimate of performance increase with no other data.

Comment: @Chris The speed increase isn't linear, it's exponential, so I wouldn't say 5x is a good estimate of the speedup.  For a sequence of 1,000,000 elements the speedup is going to be a heck of a lot more than 5x (given random values).

Comment: @Servy: Indeed. An excellent point though in my defence I did say "For a ten element array". A ballpark for n element arrays would probably be n/2 times faster but I think this is now a really rather large tangent that I should put down. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will return true if all elements are true, otherwise it will return false:

```
var Checked = CheckedPart.All(p => p);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that, under the hood, other than short circuiting, this is doing the same thing, just with a cleaner syntax.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, i know spend time is same, but its shorter and sometimes it could be usefull.

Answer (score 5):

How about [`Enumerable.All<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)? This returns `boolean`

```
bool Checked = CheckPart.All(p => p);
```

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.
>   This method does not return all the elements of a collection. Instead, it determines whether all the elements of a collection satisfy a condition.

Here is a [`Demo`](http://ideone.com/cyi7tJ)

Comment: Might essentially be the same as the OP's under the hood, but he didnt ask for a better way just another way. Plus it comes with an explanation aswell as code. +1

Answer (score 3):

Just use LINQ.

```
Checked = CheckedPart.All(x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(CheckPart.Any(q => q == false))
   Checked = false;
```

or even simpler:

```
Checked = !CheckPart.Any(q => q == false);
```

Comment: **Never** write `if (cond) result = true/false;`. Instead, write `result = (!) cond;`. In the same vein, never compare to a boolean constant, it’s redundant.

Comment: you could just say: `Checked = !CheckPart.Any(q => q == false);`.  Anytime you're setting a boolean variable in an `if` or `else`, you should probably just set it directly.

Comment: @NominSim Nonsense. It’s the same as the others’, just much more verbose.

Comment: @NominSim `All` will short circuit as well, in exactly the same times that this will.  Neither is any better.

Comment: `Enumerable.All()` will also stop evaluating the input after finding the first item evaluating to `false`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Whoops you're right. Still don't understand the DVs here, if the OP is looking for "Any are false", this code looks more intuitive to him while providing the same functionality.

Comment: @NominSim If this code looks more intuitive then that’s a problem: it’s semi-literate code. It’s on par with a beginner’s grasp of a spoken language: individual sentences may be more understandable because the beginner is more explicit. But nobody would contest that a competent speaker in the language can write more comprehensible, terser prose once we go past single sentences. Put differently: it’s not good code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The second example the OP gives seems fine to me, especially if the OP is looking specifically for "Any false value". I do agree that the first is not good code. However upon further review it looks like the OP is *actually* interested in all being `true`, not any being `false`, so the use of `All` is better given his variable naming and his actual intent.

Comment: I think just two lines of code gives no sense of "good code". A code can be seen "good" or "bad" from different points of view; it depends on the coding standarts currently applied. I have worked in projects which coding standarts force to write if conditions clearly(which I think some of you may act as if this is a bad practice). Anyway, the second proposed solution does not differ from "all" solution; not better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

alternative method (without LINQ):

```
Boolean allAreTrue = true;
for (var i = 0; i < CheckPart.Length && allAreTrue; i++){
  allAreTrue &= CheckPart[i];
}
```

Or, with extension methods:

```
public static class BooleanExtender
{
    public static Boolean AllAreFalse(this Boolean[] items)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            if (items[i]) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static Boolean AllAreTrue(this Boolean[] items)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            if (!items[i]) return false;
        return true;
    }
}

new Boolean[]{ ... }.AllAreTrue();
new Boolean[]{ ... }.AllAreFalse();
```

Comment: Should also add short circuiting.

Comment: @Chris: Alleviates a comparison check then assignment.

Comment: @BradChristie That change will be tiny as compared to the OP, if it's even a net win, while adding short circuiting makes the method 2x faster on average.

Comment: @Servy: by my calculation its more like 5x faster. Half the time one comparison is sufficient, a quarter of the time 2, etc. though of course the exact savings depend on the data and how biased it is towards true or false.